# Looking for online matlab-based differential equations course/text.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, education

I am looking for an online ODE course that would be matlab/project-oriented. A full online text/course in the spirit of [this linear algebra text](http://linear.ups.edu/html/preface.html) is preferred.

I know about the following

[CODEE](http://www.codee.org) and its odetoolkit

[IDE](http://www.aw-bc.com/ide/idefiles/navigation/main.html) the Interactive Differential Equations and its labs